# What did Chrome do to my keychain to start ubd messages under Mac 10.7.2?

Tags: google-chrome, keychain

I installed Chrome to give it a spin. Since installing I get an annoying message that "ubd is trying to access my keychain" usually after login but sometimes for no apparent reason.

I know that this is part of the ubiquity software used by iCloud under Mac 10.7.2, but I have never had this message before. I have not set up iCloud in any software including Chrome other than Find My Mac and Find My iPad.

I went to my keychain and found that all my Firefox passwords were imported by Chrome, but that they were empty--no password at all. I deleted all of these items in the keychain (all time stamped the same so identifying them was easy). I still got the message.

Finally, I uninstalled Chrome using Trash Me and reinstalled Firefox. The problem went away. My keychain seems to be acting normal again, no annoying messages. I checked the domain of the place the computer was trying to contact--it was Apple World Wide. Any ideas as to what exactly Chrome did to start this in the first place and why the imported passwords were empty?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I use Virus Barrier X6. The messages identifying the attempt to access keychain were generated by the firewall. As of now, no more ubd-keychain messages since uninstalling Chrome. Is their code "sloppy"? Opinions?

Answer (score 0):

Find the Keychain file under your user account, *Library/Keychains/login.keychain*

Open the file, it should open in Keychain Access. Find the entry called saw.apple (I think this is what it is called, if not Chrome will tell you the keychain name - I already deleted so can't tell you what it is called).

Follow the prompts in Chrome after this. It will ask to create the password for the keychain. It should be your user account password.

No need to uninstall Chrome.

Comment: Please edit your previous answer and update it. Do not create a new answer just for adding more information.